# elastic search sort in aggs by column

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, group-by

I am trying to sort in elastic search in aggs, equivalent in mysql "ORDER BY Title ASC/DESC". Here is the index structure:

```
'body' => array(
  'mappings' => array(
    'test_type' => array(
      '_source' => array(
        'enabled' => true
    ),
    'properties' => array(
      'ProductId' => array(
        'type'      => 'integer',
         'index'     => 'not_analyzed'
      ),
      'Title' => array(
        'type'      => 'string',
        'index'     => 'not_analyzed'
      ),
      'Price' => array(
        'type'      => 'double',
         'index'     => 'not_analyzed'
                        )
    )
  )
)
```

I can order by Price as follows:

```
{
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_product": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "ProductId",
              "order": {
                "product_price" : "asc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "product_price": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "Price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

But it is not possible to order by Title (ORDER BY Title ASC/DESC).

Is there any way to sort by Title?

Thank you very much in advance!

Regards

Comment: How do you want to order the Title field? By score? Alphabetically?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Daniel Hoffmann-Mitscherling. I would like to order Alphabetically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit to reflect clarification in comments:

To sort an aggregation by string value use an [intrinsic sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_intrinsic_sorts.html), however sorting on **non numeric metric** aggregations is not currently supported.

```
"aggs" : {
        "order_by_title" : {
            "terms" : {
              "field" : "title",
              "order": {
                "_term" : "asc" 
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are right I can sort it as you wrote but not at I expected. It sorts the hits in the query but it does not sort the result in the aggregations. When we use "aggs" it returns aggregations , for ex. 'aggregations' => array( 'group_by' => array('dc_count_error_upper_bound' => 1, 'sum_other_doc_count' => 270, 'buckets' => array(0 => array(..), 1 => array(...), ... n => array(..)). I am only interested in the results in aggregations. Please accept my apologize if I understand your explanation in a wrong way and for the code I've written as a comment. Regards

Comment: Edited answer to reflect sorting only aggregations.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. It helped me to sort in the aggregations. Do know know how I can do pagination using the result in aggregations? I can set the "size" but not the "from" in "aggs". Thank you so much for your help again, your explanations is perfect.

Comment: Sorry @Sensini, I have never had to work with pagination on aggs, however [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915) thread states that it doesn't exist on _term, although there are some workarounds discussed.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. I appreciate your effort. Regards